# Use of C-strings in C++ standard library

Tags: c++, std

I am wondering what is the reason behind using C-strings in C++ standard library? Intuitively it would make sense to use `std::string` in std libraries (e.g. `fstream`).

Whenever I want to write some good-looking C++ code, I become unsure whether I should start with C-strings, use `std::strings` and convert them with `c_str()` whenever needed, or use some entirely other approach.

Comment: Where do you see the usage of c-strings in the standard library?

Comment: If you're writing C++, use C++ strings. Only convert to C strings if you need to interface with some C library.

Comment: Have you seen the `fstream` constructors lately? They now (as of C++11) accept `std::string` arguments. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream

Comment: This is the type of question that gets closed. There is no clear answer. The question has many possible interpretations. If you have a **specific** example of where a C-string cannot be used or seems inappropriate then that would be a better question (after attempting to find existing answers).

Comment: You can use `std::string` always but you have to keep in mind that string literal returns `const char*` instead of `std::string`. This is C legacy, we have to admit it

Comment: @fnc12 String literals have the type `const char[N]` not `const char *`

Comment: And since C++14 we now also have [real std::string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) with an `s` suffix - `"Hello world!"s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not involved in design of C++ standard library so I can not say why any particular decision has been made, but I can rationalize about the (dis)advantages of the design decisions.

C++ was designed to be interoperable with C, and dealing with C most often implies dealing with C strings. C strings are still useful and sometimes the only option.

Now, C++ could offer a standard library interface that that requires you to pass `const std::string<char>&` to things like `std::fstream` constructor. But that would force all the users to convert their all C strings to a `std::string`, which requires copying the entire buffer which is inefficient. If I may generalize, many users of C++ care deeply about performance, so this is not a good thing from their perspective.

It is trivial to get a C string from a `std::string`, so the design of C++ standard library has the option of supplying an interface that accepts a C string, which allows the users to use their C strings without conversion, but still allows the users of `std::string` to use the interface easily. This is what was chosen in the original version of the standard in the case of `std::fstream` constructor.

Because C++ supports overloading, the design of C++ standard library also has the option of supplying overloads for both C string and `std::string`. This has the advantage of being slightly simpler for users of `std::string`, but the disadvantage of bloating the API slightly. In the C++11 revision, and overload accepting `const std::string&` was added to the `std::fstream` constructor.

> Whenever I want to write some good-looking C++ code, I become unsure whether I should start with C-strings

Then let me reassure you: Using `std::string` over a C string is almost always a good choice. The typical exception (but not the only) being interaction with C libraries.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html), C++'s C compatibility was a key language design decision. That is how C strings entered into the language in the first place. It is at that time that some of the library functions started accepting C strings as their parameters.

However, as the language and its standard library matured, overloads replacing C strings were added to many functions, including the constructor of `std::fstream` that you mentioned in the post.

At this point the major reason why one may want to use C strings is interoperability with C libraries.

Answer (score 1):

In practice all string classes can convert to and from C strings, and at the bottom level, against the OS API, it's C strings that rule.

Thus a *requirement* of `std::basic_string` variants would ask for programmers to pay (in conversion costs, if nothing else, but also header and library dependencies) for something they might not use. In particular applications built with some framework such as Qt or MFC, tend to use that framework's string types.

More notable, IMO, is that where `std::string` is accepted, there's little or no support for `std::wstring`. In practice that excludes Windows, where filenames are UTF-16 encoded. When the Boost filesystem finally makes it into the standard library, we'll have a strange situation (as I recall the proposal has language about conditional support, where the condition = Windows).

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer generally as your question is so unspecific.

Many parts of the C++ standard library were not very well integrated with `std::string`, because the two were developed independently in the run up to standardisation in 1998.

This has improved in recent years, with `std::fstream` being given a constructor taking `std::string` in C++11.

Other areas where `char` arrays may still be used is when all that is needed is a simple sequence of characters and no string functionality; mandating dynamic allocation and whatnot for that would just be unkind on the user.